# Problema com toLocaleString no nodejs em produção!

Tags: javascript, node.js

Fala galera! Estou com problemas ao utilizar o toLocaleString em produção!
Ao usar o toLocaleString desta forma

```
const number = (num / 100).toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' });
```

no mac o retorno está correto R$ 10.000,00 ao subir para o servidor em produção o retorno é R$ 10,000.00
Alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: Qual é a versão que tens local e no servidor?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um módulo chamado "full-icu", e daí você inicia o node setando a variável de ambiente NODE_ICU_DATA apontando para './node_modules/full-icu'. Porém, se você usa gerenciadores de processos como o PM2 no modo "cluster", não vai funcionar. Acabei descobrindo isso em alguns testes aqui, também funcionou local, mas no servidor não funcionou (justamente pq lá está rodando no modo cluster). Porém no modo "fork" funciona normalmente.